# А можно ли обрабатывать ошибки MySQL в php?

Tags: php, mysql

А можно ли обрабатывать ошибки MySQL в php? В частности, можно ли узнавать что за ошибка по результату Невыполненного запроса. Конкретно пришло это в голову, когда в базу закидывается запись с уже имеющимся ФИО установленным PRIMARY KEY. Можно ли "словить" ошибку и вывести пользователю корректное сообщение? Или надо предварительно запросом проверять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изучаем [The PDOException class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php)

Comment: есть не только PDOException, опять же человек о PDO может и не слышал.

Comment: @kemerov4anin я взял на себя миссию приучать новичков к нормальному кодингу. поэтому нет больше других обработчиков для MYSQL. почитает статью, посмотрит, что это удобно заинтересуется, перейдет на PDO и в мире станет на несколько строчек меньше индуского кода.

Comment: @FLK спасибо за труды. Очень благодарен за ваше небезразличие) вдохновили)) обязательно почитаю, раз это удобно и постараюсь уменьшить количество своих идуских строк кода.

Comment: @Андрей Бакша ради таких комментариев и стоит жить! спасибо )

Comment: @FLK, про жизнь это приятный юмор) Я с недавнего на себя взял ту же миссию, что и Вы. Где-то в глубине души я счастлив, что не я один да на одном и том же ресурсе. Всех говнокодеров мы не искореним, разумеется. Но давайте хотя бы плодить их не будем. Спасибо всем, кто придерживается моей точки зрения и Вам, @FLK, в отдельности)

Comment: На самом деле - старый драйвер mysql уже туеву тучу времени не поддерживается + "прошлый век" и, естественно, при работе с mysql - намного логичнее использовать PDO.

PS: качество кода в офф доке это просто полный 3.14.. О_о

Answer (score 1):

В php существует класс [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php), которым, с помощью конструкции try-catch можно и нужно пользоваться. Примеры [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: try-catch ясно. но как к примеру при выполнении запроса на добавление записи, с уже существующим ключом типа PRIMARY KEY, мне узнать какую именно ошибку вернула функция? try-catch позволяет лишь найти участок где это возможно, т.е. в какой функции.

Comment: а кто вам мешает throw mysql_error() делать?

Answer (score 0):

Конечно же можно! Самое простое выявление ошибки в запросе:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT 1");
echo($res);
```

Также можно задействовать функцию `mysql_error()`:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

mysql_select_db("nonexistentdb");
echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error(). "\n";

mysql_select_db("kossu");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nonexistenttable");
echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";
```

На самом деле ошибки обрабатывать можно совершенно по-разному. Даже, к примеру, получить список полей таблицы для анализа структуры:

```
$fields = mysql_list_fields("datebase", "qmex_users", $resourse_connection);
$columns = mysql_num_fields($fields);

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
    echo mysql_field_name($fields, $i) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Нет. Вы меня не поняли) Через предварительный запрос ясно, что можно проверить и т.д. А можно ли получить например код ошибки и зная его обработать?